# where does magento serialize the value of product_options in sales_flat_order_item

Tags: checkout, magento-enterprise, invoice

in my magento install, all products are configurable products where the size is the super attribute, a while ago i was naming the products `[PRODUCT_CODE] - [COLOUR]`, like `999MBELT - Black` however this would have the colour displace twice as the colour attribute was in the product description and was told to remove it

i have now been tasked with fixing the invoices by including what colour a product is, i know how to do this, i just have to edit the serialized string in `sales_flat_order_item.product_options` and change

```
s:15:"attributes_info";a:1:{i:0;a:2:{s:5:"label";s:4:"Size";s:5:"value";s:2:"58";}
```

to something like this

```
s:15:"attributes_info";a:2:{i:0;a:2:{s:5:"label";s:4:"Size";s:5:"value";s:2:"58";}i:1;a:2:{s:5:"label";s:6:"Colour";s:5:"value";s:10:"Dark Brown";}}
```

now i know how i'm going to go about doing this, the problem is that i can't find out where to put my code

so i'm wondering, where does magento serialize the original array and store in in `sales_flat_order_item`

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15802196/where-does-magento-serialize-the-value-of-product-options-in-sales-flat-order-it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found it, at least where it works for me, in `app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Convert\Quote.php` there is a line `$orderItem->setProductOptions($options);`, in `setProductOptions` or in a function called by `setProductOptions` is where it serializes the data so all i needed to do was `array_push` into `$options['attributes_info']`

this is useful if you want to add other attributes like material only as a cosmetic thing for orders